# The method or operation is not implemented

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, inheritance, windows-forms-designer

There are two forms. **Form2** is derived from **Form1**.

But I have an issue with **Form2** in design mode as shown on the screenshot below.

If I will comment this `this._presenter.Retrive();` it will work fine. Whats going on and how to solve the problem?

**UPD:**
If I will remove the throw new NotImplementedException(); and will insert, for example, MessageBox.Show("Test");, every time I will open Form2 the MessageBox will appears as though I run the application.

[image]

**Form2**

```
namespace InheritanceDemo
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form1
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

**Form1**

```
namespace InheritanceDemo
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        protected IPresenter _presenter;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _presenter = new Presenters();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this._presenter.Retrive();
        }
    }

    public class Presenters : IPresenter
    {
        public void Retrive()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public interface IPresenter
    {
        void Retrive();
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `throw new NotImplementedException();` do something else.... :)

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ If I will remove the `throw new NotImplementedException();` and will insert, for example, `MessageBox.Show("Test");`, every time I will open Form2 the `MessageBox` will appears as though I run the application.

Comment: By *something else* I meant some logic your interface is supposed to implement. Not just anything like MessageBox.

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ I understood. But why is there such a behavior?

Comment: you will find [Can't view designer when coding a form in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32299687/3110834) and [Show controls added programatically in WinForms app in Design view](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33535154/3110834) posts helpful and interesting!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The main cause of error is what [Fᴀʀʜᴀɴ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34567635/the-method-or-operation-is-not-implemented#comment56879147_34567635) and [Yuval](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34567735/3110834) said:

```
throw new NotImplementedException();
```

But there is another important thing that you should pay attention to.

> OP: If I will remove the throw new NotImplementedException(); and will
>   insert, for example, MessageBox.Show("Test");, every time I will open
>   Form2 the MessageBox will appears as though I run the application

If you notice, you will not receive this error in designer of `Form1`. But because your `Form2` inherits from `Form1` you receive this error.

It's because, when you open a form in designer, the designer makes an instance of **base class** of your form to show your form.  It means instead of creating an instance of `Form2` it creates an instance of `Form1`, runs `Form1` constructor and hosts it in the design surface, and then deserializes the codes in `InitializeComponent` of `Form2` and puts components on the design surface.

This is why you receive the error when you see your `Form2` in designer, but you didn't receive any error while opening the `Form1` in designer.

To solve the problem:

- You can remove the implementation, and let the implementation be empty.
- Also you can prevent the error by prevent running the code in `Form_Load` fd you are at design mode using [`DesignMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.component.designmode?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) property, in `Form1_Load`:

  if (DesignMode)
      return;

You probably will find these answers helpful and interesting:

- [Can't view designer when coding a form in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32299687/3110834)
- [Show controls added programatically in WinForms app in Design view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33535154/3110834)

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ Sorry about misspelled name :)

Comment: But what if my `DoSometning()` method is not working correctly right now.

Comment: What do you expect as result?

Comment: I want to finish the application framework, then go and do the design, and then write the implementation.

Comment: You can remove the implementation, and let the implementation be empty. Also you can prevent the error by prevent running the code in `Form_Load` id you are at design mode.

Comment: What do you mean? How can I prevent running the code at design mode?

Comment: What exactly is `DesignMode` in your example?

Comment: [`DesignMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.designmode(v=vs.110).aspx) Gets a value indicating whether a control is being used on a design surface.

Comment: @MikhailDanshin It seems the post answers your question and it would be great if you accept the post :)

Answer (score 5):

> Whats going on and how to solve the problem?

This is fairly trivial. If you would of debugged your code, you'd see that you're throwing a `NotImplementedException` in your method call, that is why commenting it out works:

```
public void Retrive()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Instead of throwing, perhaps you want to implement the actual method logic.

Answer (score 1):

**Commenting out** the part **throw new** **NotImplementedException();** worked fine for me
Now, finally method will be alike below:

```
public void Retrive()
{
    //throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```